# Delete or update multiple entities in Entity Framework code first or by direct access to DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I want to allow the user to **delete** or **confirm** multiple records by selecting them in a **list** and pressing **delete/confirm** button.

I've searched and it seems that `EF` doesn't support **batch** update/delete, so what are the differences between the following approaches - and are there any negative implications from directly maniuplating the database.

1- use `ExecuteSqlCommand` method to run a query against `database` directly.

2- or create `entities` using selected Ids, set their `state` to **modified/deleted** and then call `context.SaveChanges()`.

Comment: It depends.  What do you mean by "better"?

Comment: Before delete, you show them to the user, so why in the second approach you want to load them again?

Comment: @cadrell0 : updated question , from view point of best practices

Comment: @AmiramKorach : you're right , I updated the question

Comment: @mohsen.d That really doesn't help at all.  Are you more worried about speed?  data integrity?  validation?  How many records are there?  There really isn't a once size fits all solution.

Comment: @mohsen.d Also, it sounds like the user is pick and choosing individual records.  Or are you displaying a list, then it is all or none?

Comment: none actually , but maintainability and being standard . there are not many records ,

Comment: @mohsen.d Then stop worrying so much about it.  Just use the delete method on your context and move on to something more important.

Comment: The funny thing about "standards" is that there are so very many of them... Important thing is to be *consistent* in your own project and team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for the second option - you have one transaction that covers all of the updates which is probably a good thing. (there are some cases where it is not)

This is also the easiest/quickest way to do this.

If you are going to have performance issues then go ahead and optimize this - change to SQL or change ORM to NHibernate or do whatever you wish.

Besides - there's a rule that says write first, then optimize. Not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

Thoughts on option 1:

1. How do you plan to identify the records that should be deleted?
2. If you have an array of ids, do you plan to iterate over the sql command n-times?

Thoughts on option 2:

1. If you select the entities and need to modify them, you will end up
       loading all of the entities in memory.
2. Since the context knows the entities types and provides a delete method, you might be able to call the delete method while deferring
       execution.

Comment: 1-by Ids , 2- no , I use IN clause e.g where Id IN(1,2,3)